# Links and background color on SonarQube pages

Tags: sonarqube

Could you please specify if it's possible to have value in color on dashboard in SonarQube?
I have Measure Filter as Links and want to have some data colored, how I can do it?

Another questions is to specify links. There is Links column, how I can specify there CI link?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify links on your project in the administration page of the project. See ["Project Administration > Customizing Links" documentation page](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Project+Administration#ProjectAdministration-CustomizingLinks).

For the background color, it's not possible to change it.